# Ensure board is always on the same port?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, usb, communication

I want to make a VB.NET program to communicate over serial with the board, but I need to be sure it knows which port. Instead of programming in more advanced methods of verification, for this project I would simply prefer to keep the board on the same (internal) USB port. Will it always appear on the same serial port (COMx) and will VB always be able to find it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that the Serial-to-USB converters (of which Arduino is one) have are assigned a COM port according to the USB port they are plugged into. So if you always to connect it to the same physical USB port it will have the same number. However this number will not be the same with a different Arduino or on a different computer.

Answer (score 2):

*Normally*, the COM port number wont change, but you cannot simply rely on this.

Depends on various effects, especially if you have multiple USB-Serial devices, update the driver, etc. Also, there's the possibility to clean the COM port numbers in the operating system to get rid of unused legacy entries, which will restart counting them from fresh.

Most applications search for all existing ones, eventually display their names, and leave it to the user to choose the desired port.

And, btw. it's not related to VB.net